# hide a container and show another container on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

If a menu is open how do you hide it if you click another anchor tag? This way only one menu is open at a time. Basically when I click the anchor it isn't hiding the previous menu attached to that anchor each menu opens without the previous menu hiding and toggle the open menu on the same button.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('a, .elipsBtn').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().next("ul").toggle();
        });

        $(".lockTxt").click(function () {
            $(this).css("line-height","35px").text(function(i, v){
               return v === "Unlock Parameter" ? "Lock Parameter" : "Unlock Parameter"
            });
            $(".IntOptions").hide();
        });
});
```

```css
body{padding:60px;}

.IntOptions{
    padding:4px 15px 4px 15px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:200!important;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    display: none;
    margin-top:-30px;
    margin-left:30px;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px  #909090;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#fff;
}
.IntOptions li{padding:8px 0 8px 0}
.IntOptions a:link{color:#282828;text-decoration:none}
.IntOptions a:visited{color:#282828;text-decoration:none}
.IntOptions a:hover{color:#0B7BBE;text-decoration:none}
.elipsBtn{color:#0B7BBE;width:20px;font-size:22px;background-color:#f6f6f6;padding:8px 10px 6px 10px;border-radius:30px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>


    <a href="#"><div class="elipsBtn"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div></a>
        <ul class="IntOptions">
            <a href="#"><li>Link 1</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Link 2</li></a>
            <a href="#" class="lockTxt"><li>Link 3</li></a>
        </ul>
    <br>
    <a href="#"><div class="elipsBtn"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div></a>
        <ul class="IntOptions">
            <a href="#"><li>Link 1</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Link 2</li></a>
            <a href="#" class="lockTxt"><li>Link 3</li></a>
        </ul>
```

Comment: please present html or better jsfiddle example of a problem

Comment: <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/qf7tpnr4/2/embed/"></script>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qf7tpnr4/2/#&togetherjs=f4j4BjbtIE

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is instead of toggling the nearest `.IntOptions`'s display, **hide** all of the `.IntOptions`, and then **show** the nearest one.

To do this, instead of:

```
$('a, .elipsBtn').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().next("ul").toggle();
});
```

You can use:

```
$('.IntOptions a, .elipsBtn').click(function() {
  $(".IntOptions").hide();
  $(this).parent().next("ul").show();
});
```

This can be seen in the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.IntOptions a, .elipsBtn').click(function() {
    $(".IntOptions").hide();
    $(this).parent().next("ul").show();
  });
  $(".lockTxt").click(function() {
    $(this).css("line-height", "35px").text(function(i, v) {
      return v === "Unlock Parameter" ? "Lock Parameter" : "Unlock Parameter"
    });
    $(".IntOptions").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 60px;
  background: black; /* Added to show buttons */
}

.IntOptions {
  padding: 4px 15px 4px 15px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 200!important;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #909090;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
}

.IntOptions li {
  padding: 8px 0 8px 0
}

.IntOptions a:link {
  color: #282828;
  text-decoration: none
}

.IntOptions a:visited {
  color: #282828;
  text-decoration: none
}

.IntOptions a:hover {
  color: #0B7BBE;
  text-decoration: none
}

.elipsBtn {
  color: #0B7BBE;
  width: 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 8px 10px 6px 10px;
  border-radius: 30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">
  <div class="elipsBtn"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div>
</a>
<ul class="IntOptions">
  <a href="#">
    <li>Link 1</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li>Link 2</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="lockTxt">
    <li>Link 3</li>
  </a>
</ul>
<br>
<a href="#">
  <div class="elipsBtn"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div>
</a>
<ul class="IntOptions">
  <a href="#">
    <li>Link 1</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li>Link 2</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="lockTxt">
    <li>Link 3</li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Note that the `a` selector's parent is **required** (meaning you need `.IntOptions a` rather than just `a`), as the `.elipsBtn` has an `a` parent itself, and you don't want that click to trigger twice.